# Using an ORM for an API endpoint in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, rest, orm, shopify

I am trying to find best practices for deeply integrating with an external API. I currently create services that can make calls to APIs, but when receiving data from these APIs I find myself having to validate and sanitize this data.

I am aware it is not possible to use Eloquent as an ORM for API data, but are there solutions our there or practices to ensure that data received from APIs are validated and sanitized?

I am working with the Shopify API and there are several endpoints that I am integrating with. If I had a framework or ORM that ensured all data received was formatted it would make it much easier to work with.

Comment: What do you mean with _"I am aware it is not possible to use Eloquent as an ORM for API data"_? You can validate anything, with a `Validator`, just layers of responsibility

Comment: I mean, as far as I know there is no way to use Eloquent Models to represent expected data or how it should the sanitized (get/set methods).  Ideally it would be nice to be able to treat data from an API the same as I do from a database

Comment: Yeah, a model is a model, has nothing to do with requests data, so you have to connect that in a controller

Comment: You can use **Validator** that provided by **Laravel**. For more info see this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation)

Answer (score 0):

You can validate data even outside or requests via the `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator` facade like so:

```php
Validator::validate($data, $rules);
```

Comment: Thanks I will incorporate this into my build.  Should these be custom models I build to validate data and then create setters and getters based on the formats I need?